# Localization of SignInPage in apache wicket

Tags: java, localization, wicket

I know that to localize I need to add a .properties file that has each key and its value so I checked the `signinpage.html` in `org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.pages` and I found out that titles aren't written as `wicket:message` but normal HTML , What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create your own SignInPage and SignInPanel classes. Copy and rename them from the wicket `src` folder which is included in the download archive.

You can use `properties` and `html` files as you tried to do.

Answer (score 2):

Make a subclass with custom HTML to replace the default SignInPage HTML

Comment: I made my custom SignInPage but the part I need to localize appears to be in SignInPanel which has some logic . I subclassed it and tried but it threw an exception :

Comment: The component(s) below failed to render. A common problem is that you have added a component in code but forgot to reference it in the markup (thus the component will never be rendered).

1. [SignInPanel [Component id = signInPanel]]
2. [FeedbackPanel [Component id = feedback]]
3. [SignInForm [Component id = signInForm]]
4. [TextField [Component id = username]]
5. [PasswordTextField [Component id = password]]
6. [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = rememberMeRow]]
7. [CheckBox [Component id = rememberMe]]